# Php apcu for different version

Tags: php, apcu

I have several php version. And I need install apcu and apc for both php version. I installed

```
pecl install apcu
pecl install apcu_bc-beta
```

and after this in `/usr/lib/php/20170718/` have `apcu.so` and `apc.so`
And I added `/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/apcu.ini` with this content

```
extension=apcu.so
extension=apc.so
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=256M
apc.ttl=7200
apc.enable_cli=1
apc.gc_ttl=3600
apc.entries_hint=4096
apc.slam_defense=1
apc.serializer=php
```

and when I have been enable php 7.2 evrything worked fine. I see apc in `phpinfo` - apache and in php cli in console

but then I added the same ini file in `php 7.1` and have error when run `php -m`

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
>       /usr/lib/php/20160303/apcu.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/apcu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown
>   on line 0
>       PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/apc.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/apc.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line
>   0
>       PHP 7.1.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun 11 2018 14:23:29) ( NTS )

and it's true in `/usr/lib/php/20160303` I don't have apc and apce so files. Because I have this both files in `/usr/lib/php/20170718/`

I changed `/etc/php/7.1/mods-available/apcu.ini` to

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/apcu.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/apc.so
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=256M
apc.ttl=7200
apc.enable_cli=1
apc.gc_ttl=3600
apc.entries_hint=4096
apc.slam_defense=1
apc.serializer=php
```

and have error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apcu: Unable to initialize module
>       Module compiled with module API=20170718
>       PHP    compiled with module API=20160303
>       These options need to match
>        in Unknown on line 0
>       PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20170718/apc.so' - /usr/lib/php/20170718/apc.so:
>   undefined symbol: zif_apcu_store in Unknown on line 0
>       PHP 7.1.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun 11 2018 14:23:29) ( NTS )

could somebody help me enable apcu and apc for `php 7.1` ?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue like this approach

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-apcu -y
```

and after that I saw apc and apcu so files in `/usr/lib/php/20160303`